# Data structure for efficiently representing various "chunk-sizes" or "slices" over the same contiguous memory area or buffer?

Tags: c++, data-structures

In 2022, and with C++23 available, what is a proper way for **representing different mutable "chunk" sizes over the same contiguous memory area/buffer.**

Visualized, I'd like to represent something like this:

```
256kB memory/buffer

--------------------
64kB|64kB|64kB|64kB|  <-- "64kB"  Page size (4 x 64kB pages)
--------------------
    128kB|    128kB|  <-- "128kB" Page size (2 x 128kB pages)
--------------------
              256kB|  <-- "256kB" Page size (1 x 256kB pages)
--------------------
```

Where the `Page size` could continue growing much larger, omitted here for brevity.

Given something like:

```cpp
void* memory; // 256kB of memory
```

I have thought that maybe it could be structured like this:

```cpp
enum PageSizeClass : uint8_t
{
    PageSizeClass_64kB = 0,
    PageSizeClass_128kB,
    PageSizeClass_256kB,
    COUNT
};

using Page = std::span<std::byte>;

// A map from each size class, to a vec of pages that are <size class> bytes
std::unordered_map<PageSizeClass, std::vector<Page>>  pages       = {};
```

Where the `void* memory` could be mapped onto each of the `PageSizeClass` entries.

And probably there is some `template <>` magic that could be done to make the `std::span<>`'s `extent` constant instead of dynamic (though that bit may be beyond my limited C++ skills).

Is this a decent approach or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think the representation depends on how you want to use them?

Comment: I want different-sized, mutable "chunks"/"windows" over the same underlying bytes